# Write a Dictionary to a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary which contains the following:

```
{'Jim': ['1', '9', '5'], 'kim': ['8', '6', '0'], 'lim': ['10', '6', '1'], 'slim': ['8', '8', '2'], 'pimp': ['9', '9', '1'], 'sim': ['8', '7', '1']}
```

My question is: How do i write all of this into a CSV file?

It should write and appear something like this in the CSV file:

name x y z

name2 x y z

name 3 x y z

...

I have tried:

```
with open('file.csv', 'wb') as csvfile: 
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
    wr.writerow(DICTIONARY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the dictionary items and write one row at a time:

```
import csv

D = {'Jim': ['1', '9', '5'], 'kim': ['8', '6', '0'], 'lim': ['10', '6', '1'],
     'slim': ['8', '8', '2'], 'pimp': ['9', '9', '1'], 'sim': ['8', '7', '1']}

with open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)      

    for name, items in D.items():    
        writer.writerow([name] + items)
```

Check `csv.writer` documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.writer).
Note that Python dictionaries are unordered, i.e. this may not produce identical files on each run.

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: in <module>
    spamwriter.writerow([name] + items)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: @pythontamer: I've updated the code to for the Python 3.x syntax.

Comment: This puts the list into one box in the csv file, i want separate boxes for each entry- name | x | y | z

Comment: @pythontamer: just use a different delimiter when creating the `writer` object.

Comment: @pythontamer: cool. you want a default delimiter then.. I've updated my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

This code below enters the list of lists into separate columns (done by editting eugene's code)

```
with open("file.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)  
    for name, items in DICTIONARY.items():    
        writer.writerow([name] + items)
```